# How to pass variables to bootstrap modal form and run a mysql query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, bootstrap-modal

I have a page containing two tables: customers and stations. A sql query fills those tables with data. I defined a button on each row of the tables to open a modal editing form. For customers:

```
<table id = "admin_table_customers"  class="table rtl table-sm table-dark table-hover">
  <tr>
    <th>customer_id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
  <?php foreach($query_customers as $customer) { ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo h($customer['CUSTOMER_ID']) ?></td>
      <td><?php echo h($customer['CUSTOMER_NAME']) ?></td>
      <td><button type="button" id="button_edit_customer" class="btn btn-primary feed-id" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit_customer" data-id="<?php echo h(u($customer['CUSTOMER_ID'])) ?>">edit</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" id="button_delete_customer" class="btn btn-primary feed-id" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete_customer" data-id="<?php echo h(u($customer['CUSTOMER_ID'])) ?>">delete</button></td>
    </tr>
  <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Everything (id and data-id) looks fine when I inspect the source in chrome.
I used this script to check if right values are being passed to modal form.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#button_edit_station").click(function(evt){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
    alert($(this).data('id'));
  });
  $("#button_edit_customer").click(function(evt){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
    alert($(this).data('id'));
  });
});
```

First problem: Buttons on first row of each table shows the right value but other buttons show no dialog.
I want to pass ID of each table to modal form and execute a query to fill the form. I think I can manage to pass IDs to modal but how and when should I execute the query to fill the forms?
This is my form:

```
<div id="edit_customer" class="modal fade" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header rtl">
        <h4 class="modal-title">edit customer</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body rtl">
        <form id = "admin_form_edit_customer" action = "" method = "post">
          <div class="md-form mb-5">
            <input type="text" id = "form_edit_customer_id" class="form-control validate">
            <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="form_edit_customer_id">customer_id</label>
          </div>
          <div class="md-form mb-5">
            <input type="text" id = "form_edit_customer_name" class="form-control validate">
            <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="form_edit_customer_name">name</label>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">save</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: show how you display your buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow below step

1. call a function on button click event "edit_modal(id,name)"
2. write a function on your page

function edit_modal(id,name){

```
// assign value in modal form
$('#form_edit_customer_id').val(id);
$('#form_edit_customer_name').val(name);

//Display modal
$('#edit_customer').modal('show');
```

}

Comment: Thanks! With this solution all buttons do their job but all of them are passing first row's id to modal.

Answer (score 0):

I used a different way to accomplish my goal. Here is the link I adapted:
[PHP Ajax Insert Data in MySQL By Using Bootstrap Modal](https://www.webslesson.info/2016/10/php-ajax-insert-data-in-mysql-by-using-bootstrap-modal.html)